# MySQL stuck on INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a problem with my database. I have a production server running MySQL 5.5.33 and a local test server running MySQL 5.5.5. The only other difference I can think of is that the prod DB is being replicated

They both run the same exact SQL databases (local is a replica of the prod environment).

I need to create a materialized view in MySQL which will contain a subset of the *record_status_events* table. Below you will find the query that does this. This same exact query works in under a second on local, but halts on prod. It gets stuck in the "Sending data" status. If I export the data and import it manually it works fine. It is just the INSERT INTO ... SELECT combo causing the problems.

The underlying query I am trying to insert runs under 150ms and has 50k entries.

I tried:

- Changing the DB engine
- Wrapping it in a transaction
- Removing all indexes
- Removing the primary key
- Using the auto increment and ignoring the key from the source table

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hlh_record_status_submission`;
CREATE TABLE `hlh_record_status_submission` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `record_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Created At` (`created_at`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `hlh_record_status_submission`
SELECT * FROM `hlh_record_status_events`
WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `hlh_record_status_events`
                  WHERE status IN (21,24,31,40) GROUP BY record_id);
```

Comment: Maybe some other transaction is still holding some locks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this formulation a try:

```
INSERT INTO `hlh_record_status_submission`
SELECT rse.* FROM `hlh_record_status_events` AS rse
    JOIN ( SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id
              FROM `hlh_record_status_events`
              WHERE status IN (21,24,31,40)
              GROUP BY record_id
         ) AS x  ON min_Id = rse.id;
```

and replace `INDEX(status)` with

```
INDEX(status, record_id, id)
```

Also, you should really change all your tables to InnoDB.

The subquery (a "derived" table) will be faster because of the index starting with what is in its `WHERE` clause and because that index is "covering".  The `JOINing` to the outer part is (I assume) using the `PRIMARY KEY(id)` making that efficient.

Historically, the construct `IN ( SELECT ... )` has been notoriously inefficient, so I try to avoid it.  `JOIN` and `EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` are sometimes viable alternatives.

More discussion of building optimal indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: This actually worked. The formulation you provided. Can you explain why so i can solve such issues in the future?

Comment: @IgorR - I added a few paragraphs to my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this and decided to weigh in a bit.
Usually, first task is simplification so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hlh_record_status_submission`;
CREATE TABLE `hlh_record_status_submission` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `record_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Created At` (`created_at`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

With MinEventForRecord as
(
  SELECT `record_id`, MIN(`id`) as MinID 
  FROM `hlh_record_status_events`
  WHERE status IN (21,24,31,40) 
  GROUP BY record_id
), MinEvents as
(
  SELECT `id`,`user_id`, `record_id`, `status`,`created_at`
  FROM `hlh_record_status_events` rse
  WHERE exists (select 'x' from MinEventForRecord mer where mer.MinID=rse.id)
)
INSERT INTO `hlh_record_status_submission`
SELECT * FROM MinEvents
```

So here the intent is to break down the query into digestible pieces so that you (having the bigger picture) can figure out where the actual issue resides.